# jQUery 5000+ row .append() improvements?

Tags: jquery

I have a virtual collection manager for a collectible trading card game. My code has been working fine but I didn't accommodate for large data sets.

When a user hits the page, their collection is pulled from the server and jQuery then outputs each row into a custom div.

A few users have 5,000+ items in their collection and the page freezes when attempting out output all the rows in jQuery. Eventually it will come back with everything output but it's a bad user experience.

This is my output code:

```
   jQuery.each(val, function(key, value) {
        //Append All Collection Cards
        jQuery(".cards").append('<span class="card-row" id="cardrow'+value['rowid']+'"><span class="flex-left"><span class="row-image"><img data-src="https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics_artgame/'+value['cardid']+'.jpg" class="lazy"></span><a href="https://db.ygoprodeck.com/card/?search='+value['cardid']+'" target="_blank">'+value['cardname']+'</a>&nbsp;  </span><span class="set-prices"></span><span class="set-row" id="searchSet" onClick="searchSet(this)">'+value['cardset']+'</span><span class="rarity-row">'+value['cardrarity']+'</span><span class="code-row">'+value['cardcode']+'</span><span class="edition-row"><select id="edition" class="edition'+value['rowid']+'" name="edition'+value['rowid']+'" onChange="updateEdition('+value['rowid']+')"><option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option><option value="1st Edition">1st Edition</option><option value="Limited">Limited</option><option value="Promo">Promo</option></select></span><span class="condition-row"><select id="condition" class="condition'+value['rowid']+'" name="condition'+value['rowid']+'" onChange="updateCondition('+value['rowid']+')"><option value="M">M</option><option value="NM">NM</option><option value="EX">EX</option><option value="GD">GD</option><option value="LP">LP</option><option value="PL">PL</option><option value="P">P</option></select></span><span class="quantity-row"><i class="fas fa-minus-square quantityicon" aria-hidden="true" title="Decrease" onClick="decreaseCard('+value['rowid']+')"></i><span class="qamount'+value['rowid']+'">x'+value['cardq']+'</span><i class="fas fa-plus-square quantityicon" aria-hidden="true" title="Increase" onClick="increaseCard('+value['rowid']+')"></i></span> <span class="removeIcon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" title="Delete Card" onClick="removeCard('+value['rowid']+')"></i></span></span>'); 
        
        //Update data based on previous appended row ID
        jQuery(".condition"+value['rowid']).val(value['cardcondition']);
        jQuery(".edition"+value['rowid']).val(value['card_edition']);
                    
        //Update Card Count
        cardcount = cardcount + value['cardq'];
   });
```

I was going to try push everything into an array and then output the array like so:

```
var outputhtml = [];
jQuery.each(val, function(key, value) {

        outputhtml.push('<span class="card-row" id="cardrow'+value['rowid']+'"><span class="flex-left"><span class="row-image"><img data-src="https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics_artgame/'+value['cardid']+'.jpg" class="lazy"></span><a href="https://db.ygoprodeck.com/card/?search='+value['cardid']+'" target="_blank">'+value['cardname']+'</a>&nbsp;  </span><span class="set-prices"></span><span class="set-row" id="searchSet" onClick="searchSet(this)">'+value['cardset']+'</span><span class="rarity-row">'+value['cardrarity']+'</span><span class="code-row">'+value['cardcode']+'</span><span class="edition-row"><select id="edition" class="edition'+value['rowid']+'" name="edition'+value['rowid']+'" onChange="updateEdition('+value['rowid']+')"><option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option><option value="1st Edition">1st Edition</option><option value="Limited">Limited</option><option value="Promo">Promo</option></select></span><span class="condition-row"><select id="condition" class="condition'+value['rowid']+'" name="condition'+value['rowid']+'" onChange="updateCondition('+value['rowid']+')"><option value="M">M</option><option value="NM">NM</option><option value="EX">EX</option><option value="GD">GD</option><option value="LP">LP</option><option value="PL">PL</option><option value="P">P</option></select></span><span class="quantity-row"><i class="fas fa-minus-square quantityicon" aria-hidden="true" title="Decrease" onClick="decreaseCard('+value['rowid']+')"></i><span class="qamount'+value['rowid']+'">x'+value['cardq']+'</span><i class="fas fa-plus-square quantityicon" aria-hidden="true" title="Increase" onClick="increaseCard('+value['rowid']+')"></i></span> <span class="removeIcon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" title="Delete Card" onClick="removeCard('+value['rowid']+')"></i></span></span>');

        //Update data based on previous appended row ID
        jQuery(".condition"+value['rowid']).val(value['cardcondition']);
        jQuery(".edition"+value['rowid']).val(value['card_edition']);
});
```

However I hit a snag where I am not sure how I can do this and then update the condition/edition data based on the previously appended row.

Is there any good work-around method for my problem of large data sets?

**Edit: Current Attempt using Arrays:**
This is a current attempt using arrays. While it works, it is however still quite slow. if I exclude the select value updates, it's significantly faster.

```
    //Append Info
   jQuery.each(val, function(key, value) {
        //Append All Collection Cards
        outputhtml.push('<span class="card-row" id="cardrow'+value['rowid']+'"><span class="flex-left"><span class="row-image"><img data-src="https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics_artgame/'+value['cardid']+'.jpg" class="lazy"></span><a href="https://db.ygoprodeck.com/card/?search='+value['cardid']+'" target="_blank">'+value['cardname']+'</a>&nbsp;  </span><span class="set-prices"></span><span class="set-row" id="searchSet" onClick="searchSet(this)">'+value['cardset']+'</span><span class="rarity-row">'+value['cardrarity']+'</span><span class="code-row">'+value['cardcode']+'</span><span class="edition-row"><select id="edition" class="edition'+value['rowid']+'" name="edition'+value['rowid']+'" onChange="updateEdition('+value['rowid']+')"><option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option><option value="1st Edition">1st Edition</option><option value="Limited">Limited</option><option value="Promo">Promo</option></select></span><span class="condition-row"><select id="condition" class="condition'+value['rowid']+'" name="condition'+value['rowid']+'" onChange="updateCondition('+value['rowid']+')"><option value="M">M</option><option value="NM">NM</option><option value="EX">EX</option><option value="GD">GD</option><option value="LP">LP</option><option value="PL">PL</option><option value="P">P</option></select></span><span class="quantity-row"><i class="fas fa-minus-square quantityicon" aria-hidden="true" title="Decrease" onClick="decreaseCard('+value['rowid']+')"></i><span class="qamount'+value['rowid']+'">x'+value['cardq']+'</span><i class="fas fa-plus-square quantityicon" aria-hidden="true" title="Increase" onClick="increaseCard('+value['rowid']+')"></i></span> <span class="removeIcon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" title="Delete Card" onClick="removeCard('+value['rowid']+')"></i></span></span>'); 
        conditionarray.push([".condition"+value['rowid'],value['cardcondition']]);
         editionarray.push([".edition"+value['rowid'],value['cardcondition']]);
        
        //Update Card Count
        cardcount = cardcount + value['cardq'];
   });
   
    //Output HTML
    jQuery('.cards').append(outputhtml.join(''));
    
    //Update Condition
    jQuery.each(conditionarray, function(key, value) {
         jQuery(value[0]).val(value[1]);
    });
    
    //Update Edition
    jQuery.each(editionarray, function(key, value) {
         jQuery(value[0]).val(value[1]);
    });
```

Comment: Pagination or virtualized lists maybe... If you're willing to do a bit more work and learn new things, maybe look into switching to React or Vue.

Comment: 1) adding all the HTML in one "hit" is certainly quicker than appending rows 1-by-1  2) you don't need the `$(select).val(val)` lines - set this in the HTML directly eg `'<option value="M" ' + (value['cardcondition'] == "M" ? "selected" : "") + '>M</option>'` 3) you're reusing the same `id=` and IDs must be unique (not related to speed issues)

Comment: An alternative might be:  loop through to generate the HTML, add the HTML, loop through again to set the .val() values - this would improved the *perceived* performance (without using the 2nd/3rd set of pushes) (but this probably won't be any better than what you've included in your edit)

Comment: Great tip on setting the tag in the HTML directly! I couldn't figure out a workaround for that.